# Conditionally using packed struct with armcc (PACKSTRUCT in BGLib)

Tags: c, arm, c-preprocessor, armcc

I try to make work the BLE121LR module with an external MCU (EFM32).
As I can understand, this piece of code declares converting of the struct to binary data, am I right?
Can somebody explain me how to add the ARM (EFM32) support for it?
Thanks a lot!!

Code:

```
/* Compability */
#ifndef PACKSTRUCT
    #ifdef PACKED
        #define PACKSTRUCT(a) a PACKED 
    #else
/*Default packed configuration*/
        #ifdef __GNUC__
            #ifdef _WIN32
                #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) decl __attribute__((__packed__,gcc_struct))
            #else
                #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) decl __attribute__((__packed__))
            #endif
            #define ALIGNED __attribute__((aligned(0x4)))
        #else //msvc
            #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) decl __pragma( pack(pop) )
            #define ALIGNED
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: What compiler errors do you get when you try to compile code using the PACKSTRUCT macro? What compiler are you using?

Comment: My IDE is uKeil 5.
Some of errors:
..\bglib\cmd_def.h(846): error:  #20: identifier "pack" is undefined
  PACKSTRUCT(struct ble_msg_system_reset_cmd_t
..\bglib\cmd_def.h(846): error:  #18: expected a ")"
  PACKSTRUCT(struct ble_msg_system_reset_cmd_t
..\bglib\cmd_def.h(846): error:  #79: expected a type specifier

Comment: The IDE is not the same thing as the compiler. In my answer, I assumed you're using Keil's armcc. Is that correct?

Comment: @Pinetwig Oh, sorry!! You are right, it's armcc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, packed structs affect how the struct is stored in memory, which is often used as a quick-and-dirty way of converting structs to binary data.

The PACKSTRUCT macro isn't written for the keil armcc compiler. To fix this, we must first find how we can identify when armcc is used. On [this page](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_pge1397113341080.htm), we can see that armcc provides the define __ARMCC_VERSION, which we can use.

Now, how do we declare a packed struct using armcc? [Here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_pge1397114178466.htm), we see that we should use the __packed qualifier:

```
/* Compability */
#ifndef PACKSTRUCT
    #ifdef PACKED
        #define PACKSTRUCT(a) a PACKED 
    #else
/*Default packed configuration*/
        #ifdef __GNUC__
            #ifdef _WIN32
                #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) decl __attribute__((__packed__,gcc_struct))
            #else
                #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) decl __attribute__((__packed__))
            #endif
            #define ALIGNED __attribute__((aligned(0x4)))
        #else   // not __GNUC__
            #ifdef __ARMCC_VERSION
                #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) __packed decl
                #define ALIGNED
            #else // Assume msvc
                #define PACKSTRUCT( decl ) __pragma( pack(push, 1) ) decl __pragma( pack(pop) )
                #define ALIGNED
            #endif
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: After reading the links that you provided, I see that armcc supports the gnucc packing too...
After adding of arm based PACKSTRUCT, I get many other errors:
***1) ..\bglib\cmd_def.h(862): error:  #20: identifier "pack" is undefined***
***2) ..\bglib\cmd_def.h(862): error:  #247: function "__pragma" has already been defined***
***3) ..\bglib\cmd_def.h(862): error:  #141-D: unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is present***
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, pack and __pragma are the symbols used in the MSVC macro. It seems like these macros are also defined in apitypes.h, which is included before the definition in cmd_def.h (which is bad form - Don't Repeat Yourself). Try changing the definition there, too!

Comment: Thank you, It really helped!
Now, I have only 90 errors and 0 warnings! :)
Each error is about non-__packed structures in __packed structures.
What should be done to fix those errors? May be I should to define all structures as __packed?

Comment: Everything all right now! I added _packed before each structure that contains another structure and commented the PUCKSTRUCT. Now - 0 errors, 0 wornings :)